# Bug when last suggested edit of allowed amount is a test question

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

Question in review queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20597583

I received this question in the suggested edit review queue today - I rejected it and listed it as spam/vandalism (it was also very clearly a test question).

But instead of seeing the "Congratulations, this was only a test!" banner, I saw this banner instead:

[image: img1]

Justly so, that was my 20th suggested edit - but I was never notified that this was a test question. I was only able to tell that it was by seeing the Communiy reveal at the bottom:

[image: img2]

So in essence, the bug is:

If your last allowed suggested edit question in the review queue is a test question, you won't receive the "Congratulations!" message after properly reviewing it.

Comment: That's nothing: my 1000th review in that queue (i.e. the one to get a gold badge) was a test. Such an anti-climax!